# Understanding A simple mathematical addition operation

Tags: arithmetic

I was just doing a simple maths operation:

$s = 158 + 46 \times -1: \Rightarrow s = 112$

and

$s = (158 + 46) \times -1:\Rightarrow s = -204$

In the latter case $158 + 48$ gets calculated first and then multiplied by $-1$, but in the former case I.E.

$s = 158 + 46 \times -1:\Rightarrow s = 112$

Why the result $112$ ?

Comment: Because the former case doesn't have the parentheses, in which case $*$ precedes $+$.

Comment: Think about the various ways you could insert parentheses in the expression $158+46*-1$. There aren't all that many to try...

Comment: By convince: abbreviations are calculated first.

Comment: Because unary minus has a higher priority than multiplication, which has a higher priority than the binary plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

158 + 46 * -1 is interpreted as 158 + (46 * (-1)) since multiplication precedes addition and the minus sign precedes multiplication and addition. See [Order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer , i am a js programmer , was just looking up the JS doc's and came across the operator precedence documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence , that helped me understand what i was missing too . Thanks alot though !

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

BODMAS Rule:-

BODMAS stands for Brackets, Order, Divide, Multiply, Add, Subtract

Since multiplication comes first

s= 158+46×−1
=> s= 158-46
=> s= 112. :)